# How to fix error: "in string" requires string as left operand not tuple?

Tags: python

```
lnames = ("Mincan","Farcasel")
auth1 = input(str("Please enter your first name, Player 1:"))
if fnames in auth1:
    print("Name authorized.")
auth2 = input(str("Please enter your last name, Player 1:"))
if lnames in auth2:
    print("Name authorized. You may proceed")
auth3 = input(str("Please enter your first name, Player 2:"))
if fnames in auth3:
    print("Name authorized.")
auth4 = input(str("Please enter your last name, Player 2:"))
if lnames in auth4:
    print("Name authorized. You may proceed.")
```

So my problem here is whenever I try to run it it gives me an error saying
`"in string" requires string as left operand not tuple`

Comment: What is the value of `fnames`? It seems to be a tuple. It should be a string for `fnames in auth1` to work as the error suggests.

Comment: fnames's value is is 2 words which are "Denis" and "Denisa"

Comment: Instead of `if fnames in auth1` it should be `if auth1 in fnames`. Same goes for other `if` conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the if statements to read: `if auth1 in fnames`. as it stands you're asking python to check if the tuple `lnames` is a member of the string `auth1` which it cannot do

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `fnames` is a tuple and that you want to check if the input strings are within the tuples, it should be `if auth1 in fnames` and so on, not the other way round, as you check if the string is an element in the tuple, and not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that you defined `lnames` as a **tuple** using `lnames = ("Mincan","Farcasel")`

Then your following codes leads to that error, where `lnames` is a tuple object, `auth2` is a string obejct.

```py
if lnames in auth2:
    print("Name authorized. You may proceed")
```

You can change `if lnames in auth2:` to `if auth2 in lnames:`

BTW `fnames` is undefined in `if` statement, you could change its related statement to above one.